# SSH Tunnel to FushionAuth on EKS

Tags: amazon-eks, ssh-tunnel

I installed the FusionAuth on EKS through the bastion as this architecture (helm install from the bastion host)

[image]

Everything is okay, I can access the FusionAuth admin from the bastion host (a linux) after port-forward

Question: is it possible if I want to access the FusionAuth admin from my laptop? like a SSH Tunnel? I don't want to expose it out to public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need SSH tunnel for this. You can use reverse proxy on the bastion, FusionAuth offers ready made configuration [here](https://github.com/FusionAuth/fusionauth-contrib/tree/master/Reverse%20Proxy%20Configurations).

Comment: can you help a full guide?